# Weebly break out of content div

Tags: html, css, weebly

I would like to be able to create a div that spans the entire width of the screen. The problem is, this should work along with Weebly's design system, which places it inside a div of fixed width.

The content is created as the following:

```
#main-wrap {
        width:100%;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
}

<div id="main-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        {content}
    </div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end main-wrap -->
```

Inside {content} is where Weebly does its magic and puts all your stuff. I tried to directly embed some code:

```
.wide {
    position: absolute;
    left:0; right:0;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #aaccff;
}

<div class="wide">
    Test
</div>
```

But this did not work, and the wide div was wider than the screen, but only starts at the same left position as the content div.

Does anyone know how to get a 100% wide div inside of the container.  I could also make container 100% wide, but then all of the Weebly widgets go the full length of the screen, and its not clear how I can modify the CSS To make them have fixed width.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of that the parent has is relative positioned. So, remove `position: relative;` from element `.container`

Comment: Great, this simple solution works perfectly. 

Interestingly enough, when you are in the "Build" section editing the website, it does **not** show the div as spanning the full width of the page, but rather the width of the parent container.  

However, if you publish the website then it works as expected.

Comment: That is strange indeed. Is it not just cache?

Comment: Yes, it's a problem with the Weebly builder, the whole custom div does not show up correctly when you are in the build mode (Weebly is doing some kind of magic generating these pages). When you "preview" the site however, it look correct.